# In base 9, find the greatest perfect square of 4 digits.

Tags: number-theory

I have calculated the answer to be 7744 =88^2 as the next number after 88 is 100 in base 9 whose square is of 5 digits.

Comment: But $(88_9)^2=8701_9$, or $6400_{10}$.

Comment: $(88_{10})^2=7744_{10}$. This is not the number you're after.

Comment: $(88_{10})^2 = 7744_{10}$.  But you want $(88_9)^2$.  The bad way to figure this out is to convert $88_9 = 8*9 + 8 = 80$ and $80^2 = 6400$ and $6400_{10} = 8701_9$.  A better way is to realize that in base $9$ that $8 = 9-1$ is magic "last" digit. And $(10_9)^k -1 = 9^k - 1 = 8*9^{k-1} + 8*9^{k-2} + .... + 8*9 + 8 = 8888....8_9$.  So $88_9 = 100_9 -1 = 9^2 -1$.  And $(9^2-1)^2 = 9^4 - 2*9^2 + 1 = 8*9^3 + 9*9^2 - 2*9^2 + 1 = 8*9^3+7*9^2 + 0*9 + 1 = 8701_9$.

Comment: The *really* clever way is to punch $99^2 = 9801$ is a calculator and realize that just as $9 = 10-1$ and $8=10-2$ and $99^2 = (100-1)^2 = (10-1)*10^3+ (10-2)*10^2 + 0 + 1$; that in base $9$ we will have $8=9-1$ and $7=9-2$ so $(88_9)^2 = 8701_9=(9-1)*9^3 + (9-2)*9^2 + 0 + 1$ for the exact same reasons.  That takes a bit of cockiness to pull off though.

Answer (score 4):

Since $(100_9)^2 = 10000_9$, the greatest perfect square of four digits is:
$$
(100_9-1)^2 = (88_9)^2 = 8701_9
$$

Comment: Please explain a little more

Comment: @RajendraSharma What do you not understand? The square of $100_9$ has $5$ digits whereas the square of $100_9-1_9=88_9$ has $4$ digits and is hence the greatest $4$ digit perfect square. Base $9$ is not the same as base $10$ so we have $(88_9)^2=8701_9\ne7744_9$

Comment: But how 100 base 9 -1 base 9 become 88 base 9

Comment: $100_9=81_{10}$ so $100_9-1_9=80_{10}=88_9$. The largest digit in base $9$ is $8$.

Comment: In a base $b$ the three most important digits are $0$, $1$ and the digit of $b -1$.  In base $10$ that digit is $9$.  In base $9$ that digit is $8$.  In base $10$,  $10^2 - 1 = 100 - 1 = 99$.  In base $b$ then $b^2 -1 = 100_b - 1 = (b-1)(b-1)(b-1)$ so $100_9 - 1 = 88_9$.  Why?  $100_9  -1 = 9^2 - 1 = 9*9 - 1 = 8*9 + 9 - 1 = 8*9 + 8 = 88_9$.

Comment: Thanks peter foreman

Answer (score 0):

To have four digits we need $9^3 \le n^2 < 9^4$.

So $(9\sqrt 9)^2 \le n^2 < (9^2)^2$ and

$27  \le n < 9^2$.

So $n = 9^2 -1= 80$ and $n^2 = 80^2$ is the largest four digit perfect square.

=====

In base $9$,  $80^2 = (9^2 - 1)^2 = 9^4 - 2*9^2 + 1 =$

$9*9^3 -2*9^2 + 1=$

$8*9^3 +9*9^2   - 2*9^2 + 1 =$

$8*9^3 +  7*9^2 + 1= $

$8701_8$.

The largest four digit perfect square is $80^2 = 88_9^2 = 8701_8$.

......

In general in base $b$,  a $k$ digit number $n$ will be $b^{k-1} \le n < b^k$.  So $n^2$ will be $b^{2k-2} \le n^2 < 10^{2k}$ and will have $2k-1$ or $2k$ digits.

So the largest $2k$ digit square will be the square of the largest $k$ digit number.  Which is $b^k -1$.

Comment: You mean $80^2 = (88)^2_9$, right?

Comment: In the first part yes.  $80_{10} = 88_9$.  Numbers are numbers and $9^2 -1$ is largest $2$ digit base $9$ number and so $(9^2 -1)^2$ is the largest $4$ digit square in base $9$.